# Time based refresh of views' contents in an activity

Tags: android

Im trying to write a single activity app, extending ListActivity. I have a class that generates data to String arrays. What i want is to refresh the activity's view periodically, so it would represent actual values. I've made my own adapter extending BaseAdapter. It contains 2 TextViews in a single row to inflate with those String arrays.
When i set my new adapter in onCreate with setListAdapter(myAdapter) it works well. I just cant figure out, how can i refresh periodically the view to represent the actual values of the arrays used in myAdapter after the first inflation. I was trying calling notifyDataSetChanged() in an other thread periodically with the help of Thread.sleep(), but that doesnt work, because you cant call notifyDataSetChanged() from another thread.
Im a a beginner and new to adapters, have read tons of examples but i just cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Handler() for your activity in onCreate(), and post a Runnable to it that calls notifyDataSetChanged(). You can reschedule the Runnable on intervals however you like.

Comment: thx for the help! for the repetitive refreshing to work ive created the handler in the activity's class, outside onCreate and created a refresh function aswell which is posting the runnable with notifyDataSetChanged() in it. after that it calls itself for repetition. now it works.
however it raised a question, why cant i make a while(true) cicle in the runnable's run() function for periodicity? why is that not working? why do i have to implement it in a separate function which calls itself over and over again recursively?

Comment: The code you use in the Runnable is run on the UI thread. That's what the Handler is there for, to post code to the UI thread from another thread (you can only access UI elements from the UI thread). You would never want a while(true) loop executing on the UI thread because it would freeze your application. Continually rescheduling the Runnable via the Handler allows the UI thread to remain responsive to user input.